# How to edit .htaccess for mydomain.com/tag/iphone/iphone-manual to mydomain.com/iphone/iphone-manual

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, permalinks

I need to edit my `.htaccess` to do something like this:
from URL `example.com/tag/iphone/iphone-manual` to URL:
`example.com/iphone/iphone-manual`

I just want to remove the tag from its permalink. I don't know whether this could be achieve only by changing `htaccess` or it had to edit using PHP too.

Here is my current `htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^tag/.* /tag.php [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ a-search.php?q=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to replace the previous "tag rule" inside your .htaccess file? Because it conflicts with what you ask in this question. I'd say all you need to do is this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^tag/(.*)$ $1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ a-search.php?q=$1 [L]
```

If instead you want to *add a specific rule*, so an exception, then this probably is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^tag/iphone/(.*)$ iphone/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^tag/.* /tag.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ a-search.php?q=$1 [L]
```

A general remark: `.htaccess` style files are notoriously error prone, they make things complex, are hard to debug and really do slow down the server. They they should only be used in two situations:

1. if you do *not* have access to the real host configuration (otherwise palce the rules in there!)
2. if you require dynamic changes to the rule set by some web application (though think twice about the security implications)

In all other cases it makes *much* more sense to use the real host configuration instead of `.htaccess` style files.

Comment: i have applied this code to my website : RewriteRule ^tag/(.*)$ $1 [QSA,L], but it seem to redirect me to 404 pages, when i open my site at : mysite.com/iphone/iphone-manual-download instead of : mysite.com/tag/iphone/iphone-manual-download, i want to share my website privately to you, how i can contact you, thanks..

Comment: Sorry, only came back from a meeting now. Sure I can give you a hand if you like. Ah, darn, I just see that do not have enough points for chat. Stupid rule, actually. Give it a try here: "so attt christian-reiner.info" :-)